# How are events added to the browser event queue to be processed by the main javascript thread?

Tags: javascript, events

I've been reading about javascript's single-threaded execution model and I now understand that the javascript execution thread looks at the browser event queue for events/callbacks to process whenever it has finished processing everything on its call stack. What I'm confused about is the exact mechanism by which events are actually placed onto this queue.

To quote MDN:

> In web browsers, **messages are added any time an event occurs and there is an event listener attached to it**. If there is no listener, the event is lost. So a click on an element with a click event handler will add a message--likewise with any other event.

I haven't been able to find a clear explanation anywhere of how exactly these messages are added to the queue. Is it the main execution thread that is doing so (and if so, at what point does it actually add them)? If not, what is the browser doing behind these scenes to populate the queue? If someone could shed light on this, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but related information: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops

Comment: How exactly the event loop is handled is probably implementation dependent.  It doesn't exactly matter as long as the event loop conforms to the spec.  You may find this interesting as well though it doesn't answer this exact question - https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate#macrotasks-and-microtasks